# Parameterization of a curve of intersection between paraboloid and parabolic cylinder.

Tags: calculus, parametrization

> Find a parameterization of the curve of intersection of the paraboloid $z=4x^2 + y^2$ and the parabolic cylinder $y=x^2$

I understand that we need to find a map $M:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^3}$ such that $\{M(t):t \in \mathbb{R}\} = \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3}:y=x^2 \, \wedge \, 4x^2 + y^2=z\}$

Let $x = \sqrt{t}$. Then $y=t$ and $z=4t+t^2$

The we get $$\vec{r}(t)=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{t} \\ t^2  \\ 4t+t^2\end{pmatrix}$$  for $\forall \,  t \in \mathbb{R}$

I would like to know if this is acceptable because I've seen similiar questions on this website with answers given in trigonometric form. I don't know how to write $\vec{r}(t)$ in terms of $\cos$ and $\sin$.

Comment: Parametrization is not unique. Given that problem's solved right, you can have infinite number of different parametrizations. By the way, seems like you've made an error. Your $x$ component of $r$ should be $\sqrt t$.

Comment: Thanks, if I wanted to get $\vec{r}(t)$ in terms of $\cos$ and $\sin$ do I just change to polar coordinates? Or do I first start of by saying for eg. $y=\cos t$

Comment: sine and cosine are great when you have circles or elipses invloved, and you can use tan and sec for hyperbola, but you have neither of those.  I don't see how you get from $x = \sqrt t$ in one line to $4t$ in the next.  And I would use $x = t$ as my starting point.

Comment: I have a cylinder, so would putting my answer in cylindrical co-ordinates ever be advantageous in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Square root is not a good idea. You lose half curve

Solve
$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 z=4 x^2+y^2 \\
 y=x^2 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 x= t\\
 y =t^2\\
 z=4 t^2+t^4
\end{array}
\right.$

I got this nice image,

[image]